# Why is the interline space not as expected?

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
{\Huge 
The interline spaces are too small between some of the lines. Why so? This is the continuation of the text.}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just as an addition to Herberts answer: The line spacing is calculated at the end of the paragraph. Because of the grouping you've used (`{\Huge ... }`) the paragraph ends **after** the `}` and thus uses the normal line spacing. This is a quite common gotya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `\par` at the end of the paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
{\Huge 
The interline spaces are too small between 
some of the lines. Why so? This is the continuation 
of the text.\par}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

However, the `{..}` inside the minipage are not needed.